# Node cron job scheduling using bull

Tags: node.js, mongoose, cron, schedule

In my Node-Express application, I need to schedule the jobs (connect with LinkedIn profiles) based on the user's selection of start time-date and end time-date from the calendar available on UI. The job is scheduled to execute on few selected batch of data until the date-time requirements are matched.

I am using npm package Bull to handle the job queues and scheduling but it doesn't seem to work. The job (to connect with LinkedIn profiles) or say simple console (for testing purpose), is executed immediately as soon as the timer is set or a new job is created from the UI rather than executing at the start time defined.

Here is my code:

```
const Queue = require("bull");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schedulerJobs = require("../api/models/schedulerJobs");

var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
var HTMLParser = require("node-html-parser");
var { fetchSendConnectionData } = require("./services");
var { setLeadName } = require("./utils");

module.exports = async function connectionScheduler(
  userId,
  cookieName,
  leads,
  start,
  end,
  campaign_name,
  connection_message,
  campaign_id
) {
  var i = 0;
  var parse_message = HTMLParser.parse(
    connection_message
  ).structuredText.toString();

  // 1. Initiating the Queue
  const campaignQueue = new Queue("Campaign", {
    redis: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 6379,
    },
  });

  const data = leads;

  const options = {
    attempts: 2,
    delay: 5000,
    repeat: {
      cron: "*/2 * * * * *",
      tz: "America/Los_Angeles",
      startDate: start,
      endDate: end,
    },
  };

  // 2. Adding a Job to the Queue
  campaignQueue.add(`${campaign_name}`, data, options);

  // 3. Consumer
  campaignQueue.process(async (job) => {
    campaignQueue.close();

    return await console.log("CRON started.....");

    console.log(
      `Connection Cron For ${campaign_name} Now Points To Index => ${i}`
    );
    fetchSendConnectionData({
      name: cookieName,
      profile_links: job[i].profileUrl,
      message: setLeadName(parse_message, job[i].name),
    })
      .then(({ data: { message } }) => {
        if (message === "Connection send") {
          console.log(
            `Its Been 5 Minutes And Connection Request Is Sent To => ${job[i].name}`
          );
        } else {
          console.log(
            `Connection Request To => ${job[i].name} Has Failed So Now We Move On To The Next One`
          );
        }
        i = i + 1;
        if (i === job.length) {
          job.close();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(
          `Connection Request To => ${job[i].name} Has Failed Due To => ${err.message}`
        );
        i = i + 1;
        if (i === job.length) {
          job.close();
        }
      });
  });

  // 4. Listener
  campaignQueue.on("error", (err) => {
    // console.log(`Job completed with result ${result}`);
  });

  campaignQueue.on("progress", function (job, progress) {
    // A job's progress was updated!
  });

  campaignQueue.on("completed", (job, result) => {
    // console.log("job completed", job);

    //save job completed to database
    const jobdetail = {
      userId,
      start,
      end,
      campaign_id,
      campaign_name,
      connection_message,
      jobId: job.opts.jobId,
    };

    const schedulerjobs = new schedulerJobs(jobdetail);
    schedulerjobs.save().then((scheduledjob) => console.log("Job saved to db"));
  });

  campaignQueue.on("failed", function (job, err) {
    // A job failed with reason `err`!
  });
};
```

As soon as the server is started, it immediately prints the output:

```
CRON started.....
Job saved to db
```

It does not wait for `start` and only runs a single time not keeping it running until `end`.

Kindly help to resolve this

Answer (score 3):

for repeating jobs every 5 minutes you should use following code:

```
const myJob = await myqueue.add(
  { foo: 'bar' },
  {
    repeat: {
      every: 5*60*1000,
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the repeat feature of bull

```
queue.add({your_data:""},{repeat:{cron:"5 * * * *"}});
```

the above code will run the job every 5 minute.

https://optimalbits.github.io/bull/

see repeatable section of above documentation.

Comment: will work only when when there are 5 minutes on the clock not every 15 minutes

Comment: You can use something like this for every n second

  {
    repeat: {
      every: n
    }
  }

doc mentions that.

Comment: yes i have posted that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The mistake on your code is fixed check the below solution:

```
const Queue = require('bull');

module.exports = {

jobStatusCheckScheduler: async function () {
    console.log('hi')
    // 1. Initiating the Queue
    const statusCheckQueue = new Queue("JobStatusCheck", {
        redis: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 6379,
        },
    });

    const options = {
        removeOnFail: true,
        attempts: 3,
        repeat: {
            every: 10000,
            limit: 5,
        },
    };

    // 2. Adding function in the job
    statusCheckQueue.process(async (job, callback) => {
        try {
            console.log('Processing job', job.id, job.data);
            callback();

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('suresh')
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

    // 3. Adding a Job to the Queue
    await statusCheckQueue.add( {user: '1'}, options).then((job) => {
        console.log('suresh first', job.id)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

    // 4. Listener
    statusCheckQueue.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log(`Job error ${err}`);
    });

    statusCheckQueue.on("progress", function (job, progress) {
        // A job's progress was updated!
    });

    statusCheckQueue.on("completed", (job, result) => {
        console.log("Job completed", job.data);
    });

    statusCheckQueue.on("failed", function (job, err) {
        // A job failed with reason `err`!
        console.log(`Job not completed failed ${err}`);
    });
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You need remove all job in queue or the specific name queue,
With me:

```
async function Remove() {
    await logRankingQueue.obliterate();
     console.log("Clear done")
 }
 Remove()
```

Answer (score -4):

Any line of code after **return** will be ignored.
Try this:

```
    // return await console.log("CRON started.....");
    await console.log("CRON started.....");
```

Put an empty **return** in the end of function if needed.